# NetApp .Snapshots wont delete

Tags: redhat, vmware-vsphere, netapp, vmware-vma

I am working in VMware Vspere client, I am an sys administrator taking over for an Admin who has left.  Many users were complaining about space in our Mounted Linux shared drive.  So I did some digging and found many .snapshot files which are rather large.  If I look in the VMware Vsphere snapshot manager, it shows zero snapshots.

Update, these .snapshots are on the Netapp.  How do I know which ones are safe to delete and which ones should I hold onto?  Is there a configuration on how to only hold one or two at a time?  I would not have this concern but my space is incredibility limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshots on Netapp take space based on how many blocks have changed since they were created. That can get high with time. You can safely delete any snapshot that's not in a locked state (for things like snapmirror) and that will clear up space for you. You can also configure snap autodelete to prevent the snapshots from exceeding the reserve.

Snap show volname will list the snaps for your volume, and snap delete volname snapname will delete the snapshot, assuming 7-mode.

Comment: So a snapin in lockmode is the most current or the one being used at the time?

Comment: Snapshots are point – in – time  previous versions of the datastore volume.  The older they are, the more space they take. If it is locked, that cannot be deleted because it is in use by the netapp. Usually for a clone or replication.

Answer (score 0):

vSphere snapshots and NetApp snapshots are very different things - as for your answer, you need someone who knows how to manage NetApps to look at your snap schedule, the current snap space being used and configure them more for your needs - it sounds like this person really isn't you.